# Threading in python

Tags: python, multithreading

The gui was freezing so i tried threading and it's still freezing on me. Am i threading it improperly of something?

Updated Code: http://pastie.org/3259900

What would be the best way to incorporate threads in this?

Comment: I took your question to be a performance related one, not an actual bug.

Comment: Post the code **here**, please. If it's too long for a reasonable post, then edit it; to ask a proper question, you should be able to produce a minimal example that exhibits the problem, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Your thread class's should look like:

```
class workingthread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            chat = skype.CreateChatWith(name)
            chat.SendMessage(message)
```

Comment: Thanks i fixed that part of it.

Comment: Does that fix the issue? or does it still hang?

Comment: It fixed the freezing portion of it but I'm still trying to figure out how i should incorporate threads into this program lol.

Comment: Cool. I think that will depend on what you want to do, but definitely get rid of that "while 1" infinite loop, it is a CPU hog. Maybe try using threading.Event class, if the program is suppose to be interactive.

Comment: I'm just trying to make spam in a separate thread so it doesn't freeze the gui and to where the user and toggle it on and off.

Answer (score 0):

Begin Edit:
I initially took your question to be that of a performance problem, and not a problem in the way your Python code was constructed. Based on what was discussed a few months ago in the Boston Python Meetup, I still consider my answer may be helpful to you. 
End Edit:

My understanding of Python threads is, at least if you are using CPython, each thread is dependent on the GIL (global interpreter lock), and hence each thread runs one at a time. This is not so, if you use multiple processes. Some distributions of Python have attempted to get around the GIL issue, but not CPython.

Now, if you implement your threading in C and use one of the Python C interfaces to access that code, those threads can run simultaneously dependent only on processor availability, but not held up by the GIL.